# how to fix zero divide error in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import os
import re
import sys
sys.stdout=open('f1.txt','w')
from collections import Counter
from glob import glob

def removegarbage(text):
    text=re.sub(r'\W+',' ',text)
    text=text.lower()
    return text

folderpath='d:/induvidual-articles'
counter=Counter()


filepaths = glob(os.path.join(folderpath,'*.txt'))

num_files = len(filepaths)

with open('topics.txt','r') as filehandle:
    lines = filehandle.read()
    words = removegarbage(lines).split()
   counter.update(words)


for word, count in counter.most_common():
    probability=count//num_files
    print('{}  {} {}'.format(word,count,probability))
```

i am getting a zero division error:float division by zero
for the line
probability=count//num_files

how do i rectify it?

i need my output to be of the form:
word, count ,probability

Plz help!

Comment: So `num_files` is 0. Did you get the correct file path?

Comment: "induvidual" - really?

Comment: yes!i did, here the count values are in the range 1-10 and the num_files is in the range 20,000

Comment: And are you *certain* it is `float division by zero` and not `integer division or modulo by zero`? The `Counter` class gives you integers, not float values.

Comment: Your num_files is zero, that's why zero error. Also, kindly post the topics.txt file, to have a look into this. Thanks.

Comment: I guess, this could be the problem  folderpath='d:/induvidual-articles' , this has to be folderpath='d:\\induvidual-articles'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `num_files` variable is 0.

Check if `folderpath='d:/induvidual-articles'` is correct (`induvidual` is misspelled, but the original directory could be similarly misspelled).

Comment: Also, folderpath = 'd\\individual-articles' is the format.

Comment: @vamosrafa: Forward slashes work too.

Comment: I have encountered error, so i though of sharing it.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the path exists. If it does, check if the directory contains atleast 1 .txt file. And move the entire for loop inside an if block

```
if num_files:
    for word, count in counter.most_common():
       ...
else:
   print "No text files found!"
```